# ¿ Como eliminar la notificación "Error de integración del navegador con Plasma"?

Tags: firefox, chrome, notificaciones

Tenía instalado Gnome Shell en mi Ubuntu. Decido instalar KDE Plasma (version 5 haciendo `sudo apt install kde-full`), pero regreso a Gnome Shell (cuestión de gustos), y elimino todo KDE Plasma. Pero ahora me sale un notificacion que el servidor de **plasma-browser-integration** no se pudo iniciar. Esto sale cuando ejecuto Firefox o Chrome (que son browser que ya tenía antes de instalar KDE Plasma).

[image: Imagen de la notificación]

Answer (score 0):

El error generalmente se debe a que tienes en Firefox o Chrome instalado a extensión para integrar el navegar con KDE. Elimina esta extensión y ya no saldrá.